# how to specify default sort order in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am using a custom order function and this is the code in my controller:

```
$scope.customOrder = function (item) {
    var empStatus = item.empState;
    switch (empStatus) {
        case 'Working':
            return 1;

        case 'Leave':
            return 2;

        case 'Resigned':
            return 4;

        case 'Someother':
            return 3;
    }
};
```

In my html I have the following code:

```
<table class="table">
    <thead class="active">
        <tr>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="orderByemployeeField=sorterFunc; reverseemployeeSort = !reverseemployeeSort">
                    employee ID <span ng-show="orderByemployeeField == sorterFunc"><span
                            ng-show="!reverseemployeeSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseemployeeSort">v</span></span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="orderByemployeeField=customOrder; reverseemployeeSort = !reverseemployeeSort">
                    employee State <span ng-show="orderByemployeeField == 'employeeState'"><span
                            ng-show="!reverseemployeeSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseemployeeSort">v</span></span>
                </a>
            </th>
            <th>
                <a href="" ng-click="orderByemployeeField='daysCount'; reverseemployeeSort = !reverseemployeeSort">
                    Days Count <span ng-show="orderByemployeeField == 'daysCount'"><span
                            ng-show="!reverseemployeeSort">^</span><span ng-show="reverseemployeeSort">v</span></span>
                </a>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody ng-if="!fromOffice">
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:search  | orderBy: orderByemployeeField:reverseemployeeSort"
            id="row{{employee.assetId}}" ng-mouseover="showRowTitle($event, employee)"
            ng-click="showemployeesOrAlarmsSiteMap($event,employee.assetId)" style="cursor: pointer"
            ng-dblclick="employeeInformation(employee)">
            <td><a href="" ui-sref="app.cesemployeedetails({ employeeID:employee.assetId })"
                    style="text-decoration: underline">{{employee.assetId}}</a></td>
            <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.daysCount}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody ng-if="fromOffice">
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:search | orderBy: orderByemployeeField:reverseemployeeSort | orderBy : customOrder"
            ng-if="employee.siteId == selectedSiteId" style="cursor: pointer">
            <td>{{employee.assetId}}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
            <td>{{employee.daysCount}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now how can i specify the default sort order function in my controller. For example in my controller I want to add something like:

```
$scope.orderByemployeeField = customOrder
```

But I am not sure what should be its parameter. Can a anyone suggest how I can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a default sort order by following this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:search | orderBy : customOrder | orderBy:
    orderByemployeeField:reverseemployeeSort" ng-if="employee.siteId == selectedSiteId" style="cursor: pointer">
    <td>{{employee.assetId}}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.employeeState}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.daysCount}}</td>
</tr>
```

I moved the customOrder to be the first order by function. So initially when the page loads this order by is executed the last and the "orderBy: orderByemployeeField:reverseemployeeSort" is executed first. By this the list is sorted by the customOrder function and then we can click on the header of each of the columns in the table to sort it accordingly.